# Automatically create related model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy I have a 1-1 relationship:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class UserProfile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_profiles'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship(User, 
                        backref=backref('profile', uselist=False), 
                        foreign_keys=did)
```

It's required that every `User` always has an associated `UserProfile`, even if created like this:

```
user = User()
session.add(user)
session.commit(user)
```

Is there a way to automatically create and associate a related entity?

---

Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'init')
def on_user_init(target, args, kwargs):
    if not target.profile:
        target.profile = UserProfile()
```

However this sometimes results in

> IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "user_profile_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already
>   exists.  'INSERT INTO user_profiles ...

since `UserProfile` is assigned to a User which already exists.

ORM Event ["before_insert"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) is not applicable since the docs clearly state it is not allowed to add new or modify current instances.

Any better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The quick-and-easy way is to use "init" event, but filter out instances which have a primary key. Note that at the moment of instance initialization, it's empty, and `kwargs` argument contains the fields SqlAlchemy (or your code) is going to set on it:

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'init')
def on_user_init(target, args, kwargs):
    if not target.profile and 'id' not in kwargs:
        target.profile = UserProfile()
```

This still won't work when you save instances with `id` set manually (e.g. `User(id=1)`), but will cover most of other cases.

As for now, I don't see a better way.